# Why "__iadd__" behaves differently when used with "__getitem__" and "__getattr__"

Tags: python

Using the following code:

```
class X( object ):

    def __init__( self ):
        self.value = 0

    def __iadd__( self, value ):
        self.value += value
        return self

class Y( object ):

    def __init__( self ):
        self.fields = { 'test': X() }

    def __getitem__( self, key ):
        return( self.fields[ key ] )

    def __getattr__( self, key ):
        return self.fields[ key ]

obj = Y()

obj.test += 1

print( obj.test.value )

obj['test'] += 1

print( obj.test.value )
```

Using `__iadd__` with `__getattr__` works however when using `__getitem__` the error:

```
TypeError: 'Y' object does not support item assignment
```

occurs.

I understand that `__iadd__` is effectively `x = x.__iadd__(y)`, however I don't know why it can't be used with `__getitem__`.

Thanks.

Comment: Because then you're calling `__setitem__`

Answer (score 4):

The reason `obj.test += 1` works is that `obj.__setattr__` has a default implementation that allows it to work (although probably not in the way you want it to work) -- namely, it stores a reference to the returned `X` object in the instance dictionary.  Here's how you can watch it happening:

```
>>> obj = Y()
>>> obj.test
<__main__.X object at 0x0000024BF247B220>
>>> obj.__dict__
{'fields': {'test': <__main__.X object at 0x0000024BF247B220>}}
>>> obj.test += 1
>>> obj.__dict__
{'fields': {'test': <__main__.X object at 0x0000024BF247B220>}, 'test': <__main__.X object at 0x0000024BF247B220>}
```

Note that there is now a `test` attribute *outside* your `fields` dictionary!  There is still only a single `X` object that both dictionaries point to (because your `__iadd__` returned `self`, no new `X` was ever created).

When you do `obj.test += 1`, what's happening is:

```
obj.__setattr__("test", obj.__getattr__("test").__iadd__(1))
```

The `__setattr__` call is what creates the new "test" entry in `obj.__dict__`.

Conversely, when you do `obj["test"] += 1`, this translates to:

```
obj.__setitem__("test", obj.__getitem__("test").__iadd__(1))
```

The `__setitem__` is what raises the exception -- unlike `__setattr__`, there is no default `object.__setitem__` that allows `obj["test"] = obj["test"] + 1` to work.

Comment: A concise clear explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that `__iadd__` is effectively `x = x.__iadd__(y)`, however I don't know why it can't be used with `__getitem__`.

You've hit the nail on the head. Let's start with that, because it turns out *neither* of your two examples are working the way you think.

```
obj.test += 1
```

This is translated to

```
obj.test = obj.test.__iadd__(1)
```

And since `.test` doesn't exist on `obj` yet, the right-hand side gets translated to `__getattr__`, so

```
obj.test = obj.__getattr__('test').__iadd__(1)
```

But the left-hand doesn't get translated. So we do `__getattr__`, we call `__iadd__` on it, and then we do an *ordinary* assignment to `obj.test` on the object. Before this line of code, `obj.__dict__` looks like

```
{'fields': {'test': <X object>}}
```

After running the line of code, the `X` object has had its `value` incremented, and `obj.__dict__` is now

```
{'fields': {'test': <X object>}, 'test': <X object>}
```

If we had defined a `__setattr__` on `Y`, it would get called instead of assigning directly to `test`. But, crucially, Python has default behavior for `__setattr__` (namely, `object.__setattr__`), so it gets called silently in the background.

Now, likewise,

```
obj['test'] += 1
```

gets translated to

```
obj['test'] = obj.__getitem__('test').__iadd__(1)
```

So we do `__getitem__`, then call `__iadd__`, then we look for a `__setitem__`. But whereas before, there's a default `object.__setattr__` that kicks in and silently does something you didn't expect, there is no `__setitem__`, so you get an exception.

`__iadd__` is always going to do an operation and then assign the result back to the original slot, whether that assignment is to a local variable, via `__setattr__`, or via `__setitem__`. You'll need to implement both of those if you want `__iadd__` to behave intuitively on your class.

You should think of `__iadd__` not as "I'm doing this operation in-place and do not need to be able to assign". You should think of it as an optimization: "The class is free to mutate the object in-place". It's just like `__add__` but we can do things more efficiently because we know we're going to assign back to the, conceptually, same place.

Comment: Thank you! It's abundantly clear now.